# TWIG date filter Pacific Standard Time

Tags: symfony, filter, timezone, twig

I'm having a problem with the twig date filter.  I'm trying to universally change any post time to PST.  But if I were to post an item at 5:20 ET, the post will say 9:20pm (which is UTC) when it is supposed to say 2:20pm (which is PST).  I just want to know how to change UTC to PST because the date filter is not doing it for me.

```
 {{ post.published_at }}
```

will give 2013-12-08 21:20:46"

```
 {{ post.published_at|date("F jS \\a\\t g:ia", "PST") }}
```

will give "August 12th at 9:20pm"

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
{# using "PST" is fine too as I noticed #}
{{ post.published_at|date("F jS \\a\\t g:ia", "America/Los_Angeles") }}
```

The timezone parameter uses the accepted values from PHP. Los Angeles should be PST so it should work.
See the [list of supported timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

It's also shown in the [twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html#timezone) (or at least there's a hint) where they use `Europe/Paris` as timezone.

**EDIT**

Example to change an existing date, assuming you have a DateTime object.

PHP:

```
$date = new \DateTime('2013-12-08 21:20:46');
$pst  = new \DateTimeZone('PST');
$date->setTimezone($pst);
```

And in twig:

```
{{ date|date("F jS \\a\\t g:ia", "PST") }}
```

Will output `December 8th at 12:20pm`

Comment: Still giving 9:20 for the post :/

Comment: Seems like it only works with `{{ "now"|date("m/d/Y H:i", "America/Los_Angeles") }}` Do you need to display various timezones or just one?

Comment: I only need to display in PST, but posts will be coming in from all different timezones.  So I need to be able to convert them to PST.

Comment: Then I'd suggest to do this in your Controller. I can edit my question but then it's no twig question anymore but I don't think twig can handle what you're looking after.

Comment: That makes sense.  What controller would I have to change?

Comment: The controller which corresponds to your template where you use `{{ post.published_at }}`

Comment: Oh or another option: The Controller where you save a new post into your database. There you can change the DateTime, but this - of course doesn't affect already perstited posts. If you have any other issues in implementing what you're looking for perhaps open another question